# Show only few fileds in the list view and remaining in a dialog view Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I am writing an activity containing list view which gets data from the database. I get around 10 columns from the table in which i want to show only info about 5 columns and complete info on clicking the listview row in a dialog box. So far I was able to show all data in the list view using getview() and array adapter but not able to hide in list and show in dialog. Can any one guide me or point to link on how to proceed from here.

Comment: You can use `LIMIT 5` at your SQL statement. In this case, you must use SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery();

Comment: you mis understood the question. i want to have the information stored some where so as to retreive it when i click on the listrow.